# Problem with Sculpting Objects That have been joined together?

Tags: sculpting

Ok, so...I am attempting to sculpt on top of two objects I have joined together...However, when I go to sculpt, the sculpting tool adds onto what might be called object A, and subtracts on what might be called objects B. Here is a screenshot to demonstrate what is happening:

[image]

As you can see, one object remained the normal lighter color (OBJECT A), while one changed to a darker color (OBJECT B).This happens even when the two are not touching each other. For reference I have sculpting tools installed if that makes a difference.

Any insight would be appreciated as I am a beginner and have no idea what is going on :)

Comment: Check your object normals, they probably have inconsistently facing normals. Recalculate them by selecting all faces and pressing `Ctrl`+ `N` in edit mode

Comment: Well, that fixed the issue where the sculpting was doing different things to the two objects. However, now it will only subtract when sculpting...even though I have "add" selected...technology...hmmppff

Comment: Looks like you ended up with consistent normals but inverted from what you expected, just flip them now with *Flip Normals* operator

Comment: FYI, about colors: facing normals are lighter and back facing normal are darker. That's what we can see on your screen capture. So this is an easy way to identify this kind of problems